# MVC4 returning an Amazon S3 mp3 file

Tags: asp.net-mvc, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, download, mp3

I have a web app with lots of mp3's for download.  I have download links next to each mp3 for download.  I want to record which talks are downloaded, so the download link goes to a Controller action.

```
public ActionResult DownloadTalk(int talkId)
```

The action then calls a repository to increment that this talk has been downloaded.  The talks are stored on Amazon S3 and the ACL has them as publicly available via a URL.

I'd like to be able to force a download of the file.  At the moment I'm just redirecting to the url, which sometimes causes the file to be downloaded, sometimes causes the mp3 file to be opened in the browser (which I don't want).

```
 return Redirect(talk.Url);
```

I know how to get a `MemoryStream` of the media from S3 using the SDK but how do I force a download (return a FileActionResult) based upon either the `MemoryStream` or the url?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
public ActionResult DownloadTalk(int talkId)
{
    var talk = GetTalk(talkId);
    IncrementTalkCount(talk);
    var stream = GetStreamFromTalk(talk);
    return File(stream, "contentType", "fileName");
}
```